# In JNI how can I access static Java variable from native code

Tags: java, java-native-interface, native

It is possible to access static Java variable from the native language.

Comment: And what _type_ is that variable? Is it a custom POJO, a string, a numeric constant... ?

Comment: what do you mean by " global static Java variable" ? please provide an example?

Comment: Any type like string, Integer and byte array

Comment: `public static string name = "somename" ; `  @NicolasFilotto

Answer (score 4):

Sure it is possible.  Look at Section 4.1.3 of ["The Java™ Native Interface Programmer’s Guide and Specification"](https://www.fer.unizg.hr/_download/repository/jni.pdf) by 
Sheng Liang  .... which includes some example code.

Or the Official [JNI 6.0 specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#accessing_static_fields):

(I assume that you mean a static field of a Java class ... since that is the closest there is to a "global variable" in Java.)